# How to transmit Float sensor values via NRF24L01 module?

Tags: sensors, nrf24l01+, float

I'm trying to figure out a way to transmit four sensor values: Voltage, Current, Power and consumption but I'm unable to do that. 
Yet, my syntax is correct... what am I missing?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
#include <RF24.h>

#define ACS712 A0

int lastData = 0;
int dataSum = 0;
int Count = 0;

float Voltage;
float Current;
float Power;
float kWh;
float Consumption;
String Data;

float vpc = 4.882813; // approx. voltage per count

RF24 radio(9, 10); // CE, CSN
const byte addresses[][6] = {"00001", "00002"};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[1]); // 00001
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]); // 00002
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop() {

  radio.stopListening();

  if (millis() > lastData + 1) {
    dataSum += sq(analogRead(ACS712) - 512);
    Count++;

    lastData = millis();
  }
  // If statement to make calculations.
  if (Count == 1000) {

    // To get the RMS of the data.
    float mean = dataSum / Count;
    float value = sqrt(mean);

    // To get the Voltage (in volts) consumed.
    float Voltage = value * vpc;

    // To get the Current (in amps) consumed.
    float Current = Voltage / 66;

    // To get the Power (in watts) consumed.
    float Power = Current * 240;

    float kWh = Power / 1000;
    float Consumption = kWh;

    dataSum = 0;
    Count = 0;

    Data += F("\nVoltage: ");
    Data += String(Voltage, 3);
    Data += F("\nCurrent: ");
    Data += String(Current, 3);
    Data += F("\nPower: ");
    Data += String(Power, 3);
    Data += F("\nConsumption: ");
    Data += String(Consumption, 3);
    //Serial.println(Data);

    radio.write(&Data, sizeof(Data));
    if (radio.write(&Data, sizeof(Data)) && true) {
      Serial.println("Sent!");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Failed!");
    };
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: `I'm unable to do that` is meaningless ..... clear description of observed results is meaningful

Comment: Hint: What is the payload max size? And what would be transmitted for `radio.write(&Data, sizeof(Data))`, the String object or its value?

Comment: Have you tried sending command values instead of string values? For example, send `0x01` for Voltage, `0x02` for Current etc. That way you don't send `String`s (which in embedded programming you really shouldn't be using!!) and will reduce the data transferred.

Comment: Why not just send the voltage, and do all those calculations on the receiver, as there are just basic division/multiplication with set constants. Also, first try a more basic program to get the radio working. Were you able to run one of the example sketches, and get the radios working?

Answer (score 2):

Simple float transmission:

For TX use

```
float payload = 0.12345;
radio.write(&payload, sizeof(payload));
```

For RX use

```
float payload = 0;
radio.read(&payload, sizeof(payload));
```

Comment: here he wants to transmit the complete string, not a single float value your answer will be applicable if it is a single float but here the question deals with how he can transmit a complete string.